# How do I stop a generic function in Swift matching a Tuple type?

Tags: swift, generics, overloading

I have these two methods

```
func doSomething<T>(_ completion: (T) -> Void) { ... }

func doSomething<T, U>(_ completion: (T, U) -> Void) { ... }
```

Unfortunately, this won't compile when I try to use the version with two generic types.

```
doSomething { (value1: String, value2: Int) in ... }
```

Because it's ambiguous between the second `doSomething<String, Int>` and the first `doSomething<(String, Int)>` i.e. a single generic type which is a tuple containing the two strings.

Obviously, I can call these methods two different names! Is there a way to resolve this ambiguity without doing that?

Comment: Simplicity is the most powerful tool in programming and if your solution is as simple as giving two distinct methods two distinct names then that's what I would do.

Comment: Although it's an interseting question at face-value, I suspect the best solution would be to avoid the need to do that, altogether. What are the two closure args you're going to be passing? If it's a successful payload `T` or an `Error`, you should use `Result<T>` instead

Comment: @Alexander-ReinstateMonica - it isn't :) I used completion simply as an example parameter name.

Answer (score 1):

```swift
(  doSomething as ( (String, Int) -> Void ) -> Void  ) { value1, value2 in }
```

You could make a type alias…

```swift
typealias DoSomething<T, U> = ( (T, U) -> Void ) -> Void

(doSomething as DoSomething) { (value1: String, value2: Int) in }
(doSomething as DoSomething<String, Int>) { _ = ($0, $1) }
```

…but type aliases can't be overloaded, so you'd need one for every function overload but one. And there'd be no point in that; giving the functions different names would be simpler.